# read_html -- Error in read_connection_(x, n): Evaluation error: Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: r, rvest

I'm using rvest and read_html to try and scrape a site. The scraping has worked for me before, but it won't work anymore. Using R version 3.4.2 and rvest 0.3.2

This is my code:

```
library(rvest)

read_html("http://hamilton.edu/news/story/the-medias-effect-on-womens-body-image")
```

and my error is:

```
Error in read_connection_(x, n) : 
  Evaluation error: Failure when receiving data from the peer.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, it may be version specific or network related

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. I'm using R version 3.4.2 and rvest version 0.3.2. I'll add that in the description

Comment: Those versions are current and what I'm using as well. That would suggest it is more network related, such as a proxy as hrbrmstr suggested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrapping the URL in url() seems to do the trick.

```
read_html(url("http://hamilton.edu/news/story/the-medias-effect-on-womens-body-image"))
```

Comment: You wouldn't be behind a proxy server, would you? The fact that a `connection` object works but not a direct URL (which would use `httr`/`curl` under the covers) is making me think the proxy had something to do with this.

Comment: How would I find out if I'm behind a proxy server? I'm not too savvy with that stuff

Comment: If using Windows, then you'd generally see it in Internet Explorer's settings unless your network uses a transparent proxy in which case it'll be more difficult to detect.